# How to use Gazebo in Windows 10 using OS Build 14393?

Tags: gazebo, windows10

I am trying to use Gazebo on windows 10 with OS build 14393. I will be unable to install WSL 2. I, am, however trying to install WSL 1. Could you please guide me about any verified way to use Gazebo on this system?